# Adding controls for multiple functions in Manipulate

Tags: image-processing, manipulate

I am learning Mathematica and the Image Processing functions. I have the following `Manipulate` procedure which works fine:

```
helix = Import["/Users/dmcleod/imgs/helix_spitzer_720.jpg"];

Manipulate[
 w = ImageAdjust[helix, {contrast, brightness, gamma}],
 {{contrast, 0}, -1, 5, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{brightness, 0}, -1, 5, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{gamma, 1}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 Delimiter,
 "Histogram",
 Dynamic[ImageHistogram[w, Appearance -> "Separated", 
   ImageSize -> 250]],
 ControlPlacement -> Left
 ]
```

My question is: 
In addition to `ImageAdjust` how can I add a slider to perform `Sharpen[]`, and another slider to perform `GaussianFilter[]`. Both functions (i.e. `Sharpen`, and `GaussianFilter`) must update the image helix.

Is this possible? Can someone provide a simple example how to do this? Sorry, I just don't see how to add the additional sliders that call separate functions.

Answer (score 11):

Since I don't have access to your image I'll use the built in `ExampleData` test image "Lena". The following should accomplish what you want.

```
helix = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];

Manipulate[
 w = GaussianFilter[
   Sharpen[ImageAdjust[helix, {contrast, brightness, gamma}], 
    sharpen], gfilter], {{contrast, 0}, -1, 5, 0.01, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{brightness, 0}, -1, 5, 0.01, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{gamma, 1}, 1, 10, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{sharpen, 1}, 1, 15, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{gfilter, 1}, 1, 15, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, Delimiter, "Histogram", 
 Dynamic[ImageHistogram[w, Appearance -> "Separated", 
   ImageSize -> 250]], ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

Notice that the functions are added just by nesting them.  This could probably be accomplished in a variety of ways but this seems most direct. The added controls are nearly verbatim to the pre-existing ones.

Here is what it produces...

[image]

Comment: Thanks Andy!!!!! that did it. I see the light !!!!! thanks again. I have been wrestling with this for some time.

Answer (score 7):

A fully customizable `DynamicModule` version (using Andy's solution as foundation).

After a certain point into dynamic interactivity, you will realize that `Manipulate` is often not enough, because what you want to do, cannot be done in `Manipulate`. The below code shows a general method how to extend `Manipulate` for specific requirements. I use such `DynamicModule` constructs almost all the time (heck, I don't even know anymore how to use `Manipulate`!). It has various advantages over a simple `Manipulate`, most importantly: it is fully customizable, you can define complex controller-interdependencies, and you can easily update dynamically only those parts that are necessary to be updated, to improve response time.

```
DynamicModule[{
  contrast, brightness, gamma, sharpen, gauss, size, image, temp, 
  original = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}],
  updateImageAdjust, updateSharpen, updateGaussianFilter, reset},
 Panel@Grid[{
    {Style["Image manipulation", FontFamily -> "Times", Italic, 18], 
     SpanFromLeft},
    {Grid[{
       {},
       {Item[Button["Reset", reset[]], Alignment -> Left]},
       {"contrast", 
        Slider[Dynamic[
          contrast, {(contrast = #; updateImageAdjust[]) &, 
           image = temp}], {-1, 10}], Dynamic@contrast},
       {"brightness", 
        Slider[Dynamic[
          brightness, {(brightness = #; updateImageAdjust[]) &, 
           image = temp}], {-1, 10}], Dynamic@brightness},
       {"gamma", 
        Slider[Dynamic[
          gamma, {(gamma = #; updateImageAdjust[]) &, 
           image = temp}], {0.0001, 10}], Dynamic@gamma},
       {"sharpen", 
        Slider[Dynamic[
          sharpen, {(sharpen = #; updateSharpen[]) &, 
           image = temp}], {0, 15}], Dynamic@sharpen},
       {"gaussian blur", 
        Slider[Dynamic[
          gauss, {(gauss = #; updateGaussianFilter[]) &, 
           image = temp}], {0, 15}], Dynamic@gauss},
       {"size", Slider[Dynamic@size, {50, 1000, 1}], Dynamic@size}
       }, Alignment -> {{Right, Left, Left}, Center}, 
      ItemSize -> {{Automatic, Automatic, 4}, Automatic}],
     Panel@Dynamic@Show[temp, ImageSize -> size]
     }}, Alignment -> {Left, Top}],

 Initialization :> (
   reset[] := (temp = image = original; contrast = 0; brightness = 0; 
     gamma = 1; sharpen = 0; gauss = 0; size = 250);
   updateImageAdjust[] := (temp = 
      ImageAdjust[image, {contrast, brightness, gamma}]);
   updateSharpen[] := (temp = Sharpen[image, sharpen]);
   updateGaussianFilter[] := (temp = GaussianFilter[image, gauss]);
   reset[];
   )]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1 but Gaussian and sharpen should start at zero, and gamma should be able to go below one.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I just copied Andy's values. Updated and fixed some errors, thanks for pointing them out.